# Aptana Studio 3 Cannot create key stroke with duplicate or non-existent modifier key: SHİFT

Tags: aptana3, keystroke

After installing Aptana Studio 3 that's problem start warn me in console below you can see the error log, I am using a Turkish keyboard and Windows 8 what could be the reason and how to fix it. Below sharing my log file shorten it

!ENTRY com.aptana.scripting.ui 4 0 2013-08-01 09:09:45.980
!MESSAGE (Build 3.4.1.201306062137) [ERROR]  Unable to convert SHİFT+M1+D to an Eclipse key sequence in Open require: C:\Users\Designer\AppData\Local\Aptana Studio 3\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\93\1.cp\bundles\ruby.ruble\commands\open_require.rb
  Cannot create key stroke with duplicate or non-existent modifier key: SHİFT

!ENTRY com.aptana.scripting.ui 4 0 2013-08-01 09:09:45.982
!MESSAGE (Build 3.4.1.201306062137) [ERROR]  Unable to convert CONTROL+SHİFT+V to an Eclipse key sequence in Validate Syntax: C:\Users\Designer\AppData\Local\Aptana Studio 3\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\93\1.cp\bundles\ruby.ruble\commands\check_ruby_syntax.rb
  Cannot create key stroke with duplicate or non-existent modifier key: SHİFT

!ENTRY com.aptana.scripting.ui 4 0 2013-08-01 09:09:45.984
!MESSAGE (Build 3.4.1.201306062137) [ERROR]  Unable to convert CONTROL+SHİFT+V to an Eclipse key sequence in Validate Syntax (ERB): C:\Users\Designer\AppData\Local\Aptana Studio 3\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\93\1.cp\bundles\ruby.ruble\commands\check_erb_syntax.rb
  Cannot create key stroke with duplicate or non-existent modifier key: SHİFT

!ENTRY com.aptana.scripting.ui 4 0 2013-08-01 09:09:45.986
!MESSAGE (Build 3.4.1.201306062137) [ERROR]  Unable to convert SHİFT+CONTROL+E to an Eclipse key sequence in Execute Line / Selection as Ruby: C:\Users\Designer\AppData\Local\Aptana Studio 3\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\93\1.cp\bundles\ruby.ruble\commands\execute_line_with_ruby.rb
  Cannot create key stroke with duplicate or non-existent modifier key: SHİFT

!ENTRY com.aptana.scripting.ui 4 0 2013-08-01 09:09:45.989
!MESSAGE (Build 3.4.1.201306062137) [ERROR]  Unable to convert SHİFT+RETURN to an Eclipse key sequence in New Method: C:\Users\Designer\AppData\Local\Aptana Studio 3\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\93\1.cp\bundles\ruby.ruble\commands\new_method.rb
  Cannot create key stroke with duplicate or non-existent modifier key: SHİFT

Answer (score 1):

Run it as `LC_ALL=C ./AptanaStudio3` for Ubuntu users

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by just installing the Eclipse plug-in, and using the Aptana web view. Hope that helps, other Turkish keyboard users, by the way just open a ticket for bug, hope they fix it near feature